# Combine draft-js with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, draftjs

I have a form with 2 usual inputs where i can use this common approach:

```
<input {...title} />
```

And also i have a draftJS editor in the form. I need to convert draftJS content to HTML (via `draft-js-export-html`) on submit, and load html to it on component mount process. How to combine it with redux-form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. Using `draft-js-export-html` I keep html version of DraftJS editor content in the local storage. Parent container has a passed to child function calling `this.props.fields.MYFIELD.onChange(CHILDLOCALSTATE)`.